# What does the %Def <FTR> FTSECT.DDL %End. in AIX COBOL .cob file syntax stand for?

Tags: aix, cobol

Please help to understand the %Def, %End line in a .cob file on AIX COBOL. I am looking for explanation on the syntax and if its part of AIX COBOL syntax or some other embedded language.  I am trying to learn COBOL on AIX and any help would be appreciated.

Sample Syntax something like:

```
%Def &lt;FTR> FTRSECT.DDL %End
```

Also I find sections defined as `%Work`, `%Linkage` instead of being coded as `WORKING SECTION` or `LINKAGE SECTION`. Are these shortcuts for them? Could not find any info on these %Def lines.

Comment: Does your shop have an in-house preprocessor for its COBOL?  Compiler exits?  Does your shop use the BASIS compiler directing statement?  Have you asked your coworkers?

Comment: `&lt;` is an HTML character escape (for `<`), so this is for some kind of pre-processor for HTML or XML viewing/use. Whatever it is, it isn't any kind of standard COBOL syntax, but is a syntax for some other external tool.

Comment: Yes. There is some kind of a custom pre-compiler which they use on COB files. Thanks to @cschneid. It took me some time to find out from my coworkers.